# OpenCV matchShapes() output value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opencv, image-processing

How do I use value from OpenCV matchShapes output? We implemented OpenCV matchShapes function to compare two images, particularly, shapes. But when we obtained the answer we are confused how to use these values?

The code is

```
- (bool) someMethod:(UIImage *)image :(UIImage *)temp {

RNG rng(12345);

cv::Mat src_base, hsv_base;
cv::Mat src_test1, hsv_test1;

src_base = [self cvMatWithImage:image];
src_test1 = [self cvMatWithImage:temp];

int thresh=150;
double ans=0, result=0;

Mat imageresult1, imageresult2;

cv::cvtColor(src_base, hsv_base, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
cv::cvtColor(src_test1, hsv_test1, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>contours1, contours2;
std::vector<Vec4i>hierarchy1, hierarchy2;

Canny(hsv_base, imageresult1, thresh, thresh*2);
Canny(hsv_test1, imageresult2, thresh, thresh*2);

findContours(imageresult1,contours1,hierarchy1,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
for(int i=0;i<contours1.size();i++)
{
    //cout<<contours1[i]<<endl;
    Scalar color=Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));
    drawContours(imageresult1,contours1,i,color,1,8,hierarchy1,0,cv::Point());
}

findContours(imageresult2,contours2,hierarchy2,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
for(int i=0;i<contours2.size();i++)
{
    Scalar color=Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));
    drawContours(imageresult2,contours2,i,color,1,8,hierarchy2,0,cv::Point());
}


for(int i=0;i<contours1.size();i++)
{
    ans = matchShapes(contours1[i],contours2[i],CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1,0);
    cout<<" "<<ans<<endl;
}

std::cout<<"The answer is "<<ans<<endl;

if (ans<=20) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

}

The output values are

> 0.225069
>    0.234417
>    0
>    7.63599
>    0
>    7.06392
>    0.335966
>    0.211358
>    0.327552
>    0.842969
>    0.761659
>    0.614039

The image is [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment on imoutidi's answer. Here is a visual explanation:
The first col are the two original images,the second the canny edges. The 3. col are an arbitrary selection of detected shapes with the same index in both images. As you see, it is not even guaranteed that they correspond to the same image parts as a human would see them. What you end up comparing are different triangles in this case, which say little about the overall shape similarity. The two shape arrays are not even of the same size, since there are more structures in the bottom drawing for example(like small shapes between a thick line). in The 4. col is the last shape in the array. This is the best bet you can make to compare the images. In this example, I get a value of 0.0920794532771 for their similarity. 
[image]

Comment: Good explanation but how to implement that?

Comment: set the mode of matchShapes to CV_RETR_EXTERNAL(2.arg). This will produce only the outer envelope for both images. Drop the for loop and only compare contoursX[0].

Comment: ans = matchShapes(contours1[0],contours2[0],CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,0). Is this correct?

Comment: Compiler says: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/matchcontours.cpp:143: error: (-5) Unknown comparison method in function matchShapes

Comment: It's RETR_EXTERNAL, sorry. See:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to know what the return value of matchShapes() stands for.
In your case given the two contours (shapes) the function returns a similarity metric (value). A small value indicates that the two shapes are similar and a big value that they are not.

A good explanation is here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html (check the third paragraph).

Also check out the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317

Comment: I mean how do I use these values to compare my images. If there would be one value I can assume thats the similarity but there are bunch of them. So I can not understand how to use them. Average or check each value, any hint?

Comment: You can find which contours of the first shape are more similar with the contours of the second shape and take the average of the sum of them

Comment: This would not yield a reliable measure of similarity. With your code, several objects are identified in the drawing and interpreted as distinct shapes. What you do when you run this shape array through matchShapes is that you compare the similarity of image parts. You compare a random triangle to another random triangle for example. This gives you the high similarity values of >0.7, but it doesn't say much about how similar the actual image is if you just average that or take a vector absolute. You have to find a single contour which envelopes the pentagram, this would be more reliable.